# Optimization of Converting IP address to Country in R

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization

I Wrote a script that convert IP to Country.

How i do it.
We take an IP and Convert it to IP-Number.
Let assume the IP Address is A.B.C.D. 
IP Number = A x (256*256*256) + B x (256*256) + C x 256 + D
for example:

```
ip<-"5.102.240.155"
ip_Number<-5*(256*256*256)+102*(256*256)+240*(256)+1
```

I have another Data that convert IP-Number to country (that can be downloaded from https://db-ip.com/db). The format is like this:
[image]

The next Thing is to check where IP_FROM <= IP-Number<= IP_TO
if 16779008<= IP-Number<= 16779263 then the location is Austarlia Melbourne.

here is the code that convert big amount of IP's to locations:

```
ipNumberFun<-function(ip){
  strIP<-as.integer(strsplit(x = ip,split = "\\.")[[1]])
  strIP[1]*(256*256*256)+strIP[2]*(256*256)+strIP[3]*(256)+strIP[4]
}

geoIp <- function(ip)
{
  if(!is.na(ip)){
    ip<-ipNumberFun(ip)
    IpData<-Data[which(Data$IP_FROM<=ip & Data$IP_TO>=ip),]
    out<-data.frame(COUNTRY_CODE=IpData$COUNTRY_CODE,
                    COUNTRY_NAME=IpData$COUNTRY_NAME,
                    REGION=IpData$REGION,
                    CITY=IpData$CITY)
  } else{
    out<-NULL
  }

  return(out)
}

outcomes <- lapply(X = BigArrayOfIP$ip,FUN =  geoIp)
```

The problem is that this script does'nt end to run.
I think that the problem is in the line:

```
IpData<-Data[which(Data$IP_FROM<=ip & Data$IP_TO>=ip),]
```

Data is very big file. it contains 9364224 Rows.
How can i optimize the script.
Thanks!

Comment: Insert `browser()` as your first line, rerun the definition and run the function.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Ok, I did it. it still run very slow.

Comment: Ah, I thought it doesn't run because of a bug, sorry.

Comment: To cut the redundant fat, which noone can reproduce: you want a fast way to check whether an integer number is between a range of integer numbers? Check the numerous posts on `foverlaps` (`data.table` package).

Answer (score 2):

You can get a lot of speed gains using `data.table`

Lets assume you have a `data.table` of IP addresses, structured like:

```
library(data.table)
dt_ips <- data.table(ip_string = c("100.100.100.100", "...", "etc"))  
## This will likely be your 'BigArrayOfIP'
```

You can then convert each value into an integer using your `ipNumberFun`

```
## This update by reference is not working
## dt_ips[, ip := ipNumberFun(ip_string)]
## so instead, we can use
dt_ips <- dt_ips[, .(ip = ipNumberFun(ip_string)), by=ip_string]
```

Now we can use these newly formed integers, and find where the fit into your `Data` lookup table

For example, assume the result of my previouis operation gives:

```
dt_ips <- data.table(ip = c(16778245, 16777213, 16778497))
> dt_ips
#         ip
#1: 16778245
#2: 16777213
#3: 16778497
```

and we set `Data` to be a `data.table`

```
setDT(Data)
Data
# IP_FROM    IP_TO COUNTRY_CODE      CITY
# 1:        0 16777215            .         .
# 2: 16777216 16777471    Australia  Brisbane
# 3: 16777472 16778239        China    Fuzhou
# 4: 16778240 16778495    Australia Melbourne
# 5: 16778496 16779007    Australia    Sydney
# 6: 16779008  1677923    Australia Melbourne
```

Then we have a few ways of finding where the `ip` integer fits into this table using the `data.table` package. The simplest would be to just join it all together and filter out incorrect results:

Define a common key column and join the two tables togeter, then filter out incorrect results.

```
Data[ , key_col := 1][ dt_ips[, key_col := 1], on="key_col", allow.cartesian = T][IP_FROM <= ip & ip < IP_TO]


#        CITY COUNTRY_CODE  IP_FROM    IP_TO key_col       ip
#1: Melbourne    Australia 16778240 16778495       1 16778245
#2:         .            .        0 16777215       1 16777213
#3:    Sydney    Australia 16778496 16779007       1 16778497
```

**Edit - Alternative solution**

The error you're seeing suggests the result of the 'join everything together' method will not work as there are too many rows in the result.

An alternative, as the error message suggests, is to perform the join on each `I` in `J`

```
dt_ips[, key_col := 1]
DATA[, key_col := 1]

dt <- DATA[dt_ips, 
           {
             idx = IP_FROM <= ip & ip < IP_TO
             .(ip_string = i.ip,
               IP_FROM = IP_FROM[idx],
               IP_TO = IP_TO[idx],
               COUNTRY_CODE = COUNTRY_CODE[idx],
               CITY = CITY[idx])
           },
           on=c("key_col"),
           by=.EACHI]
```

**Edit - foverlap solution**

Or, we can try an `foverlap` solution

```
DATA <- DATA[, .(COUNTRY_CODE, CITY, IP_FROM, IP_TO)]

dt_ips[, `:=`(IP_FROM = ip, IP_TO = ip)]

setkey(DATA, IP_FROM, IP_TO)
setkey(dt_ips, IP_FROM, IP_TO)

foverlaps(dt_ips, 
          DATA)
```

**Edit - Data**

The OP is using this data:

```
dput(head(dt_ips))
structure(list(ip_string = c("71.190.193.124", "70.130.142.86", 
"66.32.18.22", "87.155.51.131", "217.195.236.114", "162.195.53.38"
), ip = c(1203683708, 1203683708, 1203683708, 1203683708, 1203683708, 
1203683708)), .Names = c("ip_string", "ip"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000013f0788>)
```

Comment: I ran this script:library(data.table)      
`dt_ips <- data.table(ip_string = na.omit(ip)) 
dt_ips[, ip := ipNumberFun(ip_string)]
setDT(Data)
Data[ , key_col := 1][ dt_ips[, key_col := 1], on="key_col", allow.cartesian = T][IP_FROM <= ip & ip < IP_TO]`

Comment: and got this error:Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.

Comment: dt_ips is unique, the version of data.table is 1.9.6

Comment: Another thing in this script. the line `dt_ips[, ip := ipNumberFun(ip_string)]` return data frame where the ip column is the same number.

Comment: `dput(head(dt_ips))
structure(list(ip_string = c("71.190.193.124", "70.130.142.86", 
"66.32.18.22", "87.155.51.131", "217.195.236.114", "162.195.53.38"
), ip = c(1203683708, 1203683708, 1203683708, 1203683708, 1203683708, 
1203683708)), .Names = c("ip_string", "ip"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000013f0788>)`

Comment: @dmitriy I've also edited my question. See the line where I'm now using `dt_ips <- dt_ips[, .(ip = ipNumberFun(ip_string)), by=ip_string]` in place of `dt_ips[, ip := ipNumberFun(ip_string)]`

Comment: It still give me this error: Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.

Comment: But now the ip column is different to each ip string

Comment: @dmitriy I've proposed an alternative solution that should get around the memory allocation issue

Comment: @dmitriy and i've also updated it with an `foverlap` solution